# .NET Regex negative lookbehind not working

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to match the following text (anywhere in the string) where string can be anything between A and ;

```
Astring;
```

However I don't want to match the following

```
aAstring;
AAstring;
```

The expression `(?<![A|a])A.*?;`  works ok for aAstring; but not for AAstring;

It seems that the lookaround doesn't work for the same character?  I must be missing something simple here.

Comment: That's a lookbehind, not a lookahead.

Comment: `[A|a]` is not doing what you think. (The expression you want here is `[Aa]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that's a lookbehind, not a lookahead. To understand what's going on here, break down what the regex is saying:

```regex
(?<![A|a])A #An A that is not preceded by A, a, or a literal |
.?;         #Any number of characters followed by ;
```

Now consider your input, `AAstring`:

```
A       #An A that is not preceded by A (because it's at the beginning of the string)
Astring #Some characters followed by ;
```

So the lookbehind is working, it just doesn't do what you think it does. I think what you want is something like this:

```regex
^(?![Aa]{2})A.*?;
```

That anchors itself to the beginning of the string, so you know where the lookahead is going to look. Here's what it means:

```regex
^           #Beginning of the line
(?![Aa]{2}) #"The following string must not start with two As in a row, regardless of case"
A.*?;       #Capital A followed by anything followed by ;
```

You could also try

```
\b(?![Aa]{2})A.*?;
```

if your target isn't at the very beginning of the line.

Note that this is actually the same as `^A(?![Aa]).*?;` or `\bA(?![Aa]).*?;`, but the above might be easier to understand.

Comment: This is close however my target expression might be embedded in another string.

Comment: @Jake1164 - The `\b` version should be what you need, then. Since you're using .NET, don't forget to make the pattern a [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) by using `@"\bA(?![Aa]).*?"` instead of `"\bA(?![Aa]).*?"`.

Answer (score 2):

If the `string` part can be any string, then it matches correctly. The `A` in the regex matches with the first `A` in the text and `.*?` matches with `Astring`. And there is no `A` or `a` before the first `A`.

If you have some rules for the `string` part, then you should add them and it should fix your problem.

Comment: yes string can be anything (thanks I updated the question). I tried updating the regex to (?<![A|a])A(.*?); and get the same results.

Comment: If string can be anything, then it can be `Astring` too. Which would mean the results you are getting are correct.

Comment: This was also a key help to my resolution.. I had to define the "string" to be slightly more than any string.

Answer (score 2):

The negative look-behind is working correctly. To achieve what you're attempting I suggest using a negative look-ahead, as shown in this pattern: `"A(?![Aa]).*?;"`

It will match `A` then fail to match if the next character is either `A` or `a`. If you want to ensure the string begins with `A` rather than being a partial match within a larger string, add the `\b` metacharacter to the beginning of the pattern: `@"\bA(?![Aa]).*?;"`